# Translating escaped format special characters to normal format using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to create XSL to translate escaped format special characters to normal format.

To be more specific, below is an example of the text with escaped format special characters:

```
&amp;lt;p attribute1='value 1' attribute2='value 2'&amp;gt; &amp;lt;ph attribute3='value 3' amp;gt;TEXT&amp;lt;/ph&amp;gt; &amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
```

Here is the XML that I would like to produce from the above:

```
<p attribute1="value 1" attribute2="value 2"><ph attribute3="value 3">TEXT</ph></p>
```

Has anyone done anything like this before?

Thank you.

Comment: If all you want is unescape the string, you can output it using `disable-output-escaping`.

Comment: Is that input part of an XML document? Or part of a plain text document? Which rules were used to escape the input, is it kind of double escaped?

Comment: Even with double escaping, the part `attribute3='value 3' amp;gt;` seems to be wrong and would need to be `attribute3='value 3' &amp;gt;`, to unescape it properly.